# Preset ratings for a comparator circuit

Tags: resistors, comparator

1)What are the rating for these kind of presets?
  I need the maximum current they can withstand without any harm, (Imax).
  [data need for a 100k preset]

[image: preset]

[image]

---

2)I'm hoping to use this kind of voltage divider method to set reference voltages to a     voltage comparator circuit. Because ref voltage should be able to adjust. Is there any good method to set reference voltages rather than this?

Comment: The weak link is not what current enters the top or bottom of the resistor but what enters or leaves the wiper.

Comment: How much voltage are you using that you would put enough power into a 100k trimmer to damage it?

Comment: I haven't decided the Vmax yet. To decide that I need the maximum current (Imax) that the preset can withstand. Assume that output draws no current.

Comment: I'd consider using a multi-turn pot for setting a control voltage on a comparator - more reliable and easier to set the precise value because they are multi-turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one you could use: -

[image]

The important parameters are shown in red

- Wiper current = 50 mA
- Power rating = 0.2 W
- Max voltage across pot = 100 Vdc

If you use the maximum power limit (0.2 W) and the resistance (100 k\$\Omega\$) you can calculate the maximum allowable voltage across the device: -

\$Power = \dfrac{Voltage^2}{Resistance}\$ therefore voltage = \$\sqrt{0.2\times 100k}\$ = 141V.

However, it says in the spec the voltage limit is 100 Vdc so, what current would flow into the 100 k\$\Omega\$ pot if this voltage were applied? Answer is 1 mA.

This tells you that you need to ensure you don't put more than 100 V across it and you won't get more than 1 mA and your power rating won't be exceeded.

Because the value of the pot is so high, it will never pass enough current to cause a problem with the wiper. This statement is made with the understanding that the wiper takes no current as per a comment made by the OP.

However, it's very important that if you have a circuit where the wiper does draw current, you keep it well within the boundaries stated in the data sheet.

Comment: @DaveTweed I shall add what the OP says in one of his comments about not using the wiper into a load.

Answer (score 0):

I used pots like this one up to 7-9mA any higher than that tends to be damaging them.

Comment: I dont need to pass a much current It would be 5mA<. So Imax will not become a big issue I guess. Thank you.